# Does the Timer(callback,...) callback function add to the stack? garbage collection Q with this

Tags: c#, timer, garbage-collection, callstack

I have a function that needs to archive 90 day old emails every midnight. I created a class to handle this and here's the example:

```
    public void processArchives()
    {
        initializeTimer();
    }

    private void initializeTimer()
    {
        var now = DateTime.Now;
        var tomorrow = now.AddDays(1);
        var durationUntilMidnight = tomorrow.Date - now;

        var t = new Timer(o => { attemptArchivalProcess(); }, null, TimeSpan.Zero, durationUntilMidnight);
    }

    private void attemptArchivalProcess()
    {
        //perform archival
        initializeTimer(); //re-start timer to process tomorrow
    }
```

question is, will the repeated calls to initializeTimer cause a stack overflow (repeated function calls) or will it run fine 'forever'?

and should I be able to call processArchives() as a new thread, and keep the thread open or do I need some sort of loop after the init call something like:

```
    while(!Program.Closing){ sleep(...); }
```

to keep it from being garbage collected?

Comment: You almost certainly shouldn't have a C# application that runs for that long.  Have the code to do the processing once, and then just use Windows Task Scheduler to run it every night at midnight.  It will be much more robust than your code, able to handle things like restarting the machine, changing the system clock, etc.

Comment: @Servy This is just a module for a service that handles several aspects of an Email Queueing system that runs 24/7 anyways.

Comment: That doesn't change my comment.  You should be scheduling the job rather than running it 24/7.

Comment: @Servy Not that I completly disagree, but isn't "an application that runs 24/7" something very very close to a windows service? A backup service would look a lot alike to what OP is asking, seems nothing wrong with that or am I missing something?

Comment: @bas I wasn't advocating a windows service.  That would be a bit better, but still not quite as effective as simply scheduling a task with the task scheduler.  It means the job isn't sitting there doing nothing all of the time, and it simplifies a lot of the clock related issues such as daylight savings, periodic clock adjustments, etc.

Comment: @Servy unfortunately there's no 100% reliable way to get the task scheduler working. We've had a lot of MS certified IT staff try over the years. We can get it working 99%, but not 100% :-) The most reliable solution is to have it as a service or "always on" application of some sort

Comment: @DiskJunky If you have more complex scheduling logic than "once a day at mightnight" maybe, but for this particular use case, I fail to see why the windows scheduler wouldn't work just fine.

Comment: @Servy in general I agree but we don't know the exact use case. Personally, we've had scheduling failures even on simple "run once a day" schedules from windows XP up. All our critical schedule software is now service based as a result. I really wish we didn't have to but... Anyhoo, we're getting off topic a little :-)

Comment: Sorry...To clarify...the Email Queueing system I'm referring to is a Service that I wrote. So this module will be run on an additional thread within the service. This way the service is less 'fragmented'. There's not really any reason for me to write a separate application to be ran at the specified interval separately.

Comment: gave it my best go in an answer, I hope it helps

Comment: @phillk6751, revised my answer with a simplified example. I hope I am not drifting away and that it makes sense to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are close to your potential solution.

## Timer

*To answer your first question*: As you already concluded the timer will elapse on it's delegate. The delegate will be executed on a separate thread and each timer elapse will get a brand new fresh own stack to execute on. Thus, endless timer elapsed events will never trigger a `StackOverflowException`.

## Wait until forever?

*An attempt to answer your second question*: You don't **have** to write an endless loop to keep your application alive. But, you could do that, it all depends on what you need for your application. Weigh the pros and cons.

Luckily there are more solutions possible (there is no right or wrong, weigh them out to fulfill your needs)

A shot list of solutions you could concider:

### Console.ReadLine()

If you have a console application, you could simply wait for user input. The main thread will wait forever without consuming processor power.

### As suggested by Servy, create a scheduled task

That way you don't have to do anything at all to write endless loops. Your application will simply exit when it's done. Might not be the most handsome solution if you actually deploy this app to users.

### Windows service

You could also go for a bit more mature solution and write a windows service (sounds more complicated than it is, it's pretty simple to write a basic windows service). That way you also don't have to bother about writing never ending loops, a windows service will run forever by design (unit you decide to stop it of course)

### Alternative for never ending while loop - WaitHandle

You could also use a signal mechanism (e.g. with a `AutoResetEvent`) so that your main thread can Wait until a certain signal is set. That way you also don't have to *actively wait* (=not consume processor cycles).

You have tons of alternatives, it all boils down to your specific needs, which I can't decide for you. **You can. :)**

---

All those words, let's throw in an example. The unit test represents your application. The timer is a different type, namely the `System.Timers.Timer`. You can set that timer to `AutoReset` so that you don't have to create new timers.

Here the example, I hope it makes sense to you (if not, comment, maybe I can clarify)

```
    private Timer _processTimer;
    private AutoResetEvent _resetSignal;

    [Test]
    public void YourImaginaryMainApp()
    {
        const int interval = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // every day

        _resetSignal = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        _processTimer = new Timer(interval)
            {
                AutoReset = true
            };
        _processTimer.Elapsed += ProcessTimerOnElapsed;

        _resetSignal.WaitOne( /*infinite*/);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit x1** - meant "heap", not "stack" in second sentence... (d'oh!)

I don't think this will cause a stack overflow for a very simple reason. The line `var t = new Timer(`... creates a new object on the heap. The function pointer is kept internally within the object and should (in theory) never be added to the stack until it's actually called. When `attemptArchivalProcess()` is called, it in turns calls `initializeTimer()` (adding to the stack) but this then completes and exits as normal on the same thread (removing from the stack). When the `Timer` does kick in, it'll start off that 2-call entry to the stack.

Now, all this said, I know there is increased complexity going on under the hood with the stack but my point is that ultimately that you have 2 methods being called which then exit correctly - and should be cleaned up correctly when they exit.

Or at least that's my reasoning. I fully admit I'm open to correction on this though...

Comment: Are you sure `var t = new Timer(...)` creates an object on the stack? Besides, does it even matter for your argument? If it doesn't matter, it's usually better to ignore implementation details like this. Makes your argument more universal and removes a point of failure.

Comment: @delnan see edit. I meant to say that creating a new object happens on the heap, not the stack. You can create objects on the help until the machine's commit memory runs out (actual size depends on machine RAM/page file/configuration)

Comment: ah...looking through MSDN found this: Use a TimerCallback delegate to specify the method you want the Timer to execute. The timer delegate is specified when the timer is constructed, and cannot be changed. The method does not execute on the thread that created the timer; it executes on a ThreadPool thread supplied by the system.

It also turns out that I must keep a reference to the Timer object, so I will need to modify my class to have a class-level variable, not a function-level variable for the Timer object.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempted resolution for this....

```
    System.Threading.Timer timerFunc = null;

    public void processArchives()
    {
        initializeTimer();

        while (!CSEmailQueues.StoppingService) //is
            Thread.Sleep(CSEmailQueues.sleeptime); 

        timerFunc.Dispose();

        return;
    }

    private void initializeTimer()
    {
        var now = DateTime.Now;
        var tomorrow = now.AddDays(1);
        var durationUntilMidnight = tomorrow.Date - now;

        if (timerFunc != null) timerFunc.Dispose();
        timerFunc = new System.Threading.Timer(o => { attemptArchivalProcess(); }, null, TimeSpan.Zero, durationUntilMidnight);
    }

    private void attemptArchivalProcess()
    {
        //Do Work
        initializeTimer(); //re-start timer to process tomorrow
    }
```

So...this will dispose the timer object and create a new one each time it runs (as this timer only executes once). Plus being a class level variable, there is always a reference to the timer so the garbage collector doesn't dispose of it while i'm waiting for it to trigger.

Then all I have to do is create a thread that calls processArchives() from the onStart call for the service, and this should in essence run forever unless the onStop is called and sets StoppingService to true.

Also I am guessing I shouldn't have to worry about cross-thread use of timerFunc by the timer callback as there should never be more than 1 instance at any given time to access this object.